# TFS 2013 Error TF246091

Tags: tfs

I am trying to migrate a collection from one TFS Server 2013 update 4 to another TFS Server 2013 RTM, when running the verify command i get this error: TF246091: The team project collection cannot be attached because its version ID is higher than the ID for the configuration database. The collection has the following version: Dev12.M73. The Team Foundation Server is at the following version: Dev12.M53.

I found out the pb is in TFS_Config (configuration database) and not in the collection.

What to do ?
Can i downgrade my source TFS server, since i can't upgrade the destination server (prod environment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to downgrade a collection. You must upgrade TFS to at least the collection level to attach it.